# How to add headers on Nuxt static files response?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors, frontend, nuxt.js

I have a json file on static folder and I'm trying to access it from another web site, but I'm having problem with the CORS.

How can I add headers (like Access-Control-Allow-Origin) on the static files response?

I tried this https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/2554#issuecomment-363795301, but didn't work for static files.

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', '*');
    next()
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Nuxt has a build in render property option, that you can use inside the nuxt.config.js file.

If you want to add Access-Control Headers for static files just use the `setHeaders` function.

See https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render#static.

In the background Nuxt uses the [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) package (also for other options).

Example:

```
render: {
   static: {
     setHeaders(res) {
       res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOWALL')
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET')
       res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept')
  }
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this is only working in development and not in production?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using axios to make HTTP calls you might want to use [Nuxt version of Axios](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/). 
There you can easily use [option](https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options.html) `proxy` in combination with [Proxy Module](https://github.com/nuxt-community/proxy-module)

Comment: This method is not working for me in production on netlify