# How to add CORS headers on Nuxt static files responses in production?

Tags: azure, express, cors, nuxt.js

I've added the headers necessary for CORS by using the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044101/how-to-add-headers-on-nuxt-static-files-response). This works on development but when I use it on production, the headers aren't set.

How do I make it work on production as well?

nuxt.config.ts

```
const config: Configuration = {
  mode: 'universal',
  render: {
    static: {
      // Add CORS header to static files.
      setHeaders(res: express.Response) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
        res.setHeader(
          'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
          'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept'
        );
      },
    },
  },
  // etc
}
```

Production
[image]

Development
[image]

Comment: I've added OPTIONS requests as well to include preflights. To no avail.
`res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS');`

Answer (score 0):

Eventually it was a setting in the Azure settings of my app service. I had to enable CORS.

[image]