# Serve static assets with an efficient cache policy - Nuxt.js + GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, caching, nuxt.js, cache-control, lighthouse

I get the following from **Lighthouse**:

[image]

How do I change the Cache TTL on a **Nuxt.js** SSR website? I found some answers but nothing about Nuxt.js...

**IMPORTANT**: Deployed in Google App Engine

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add headers on Nuxt static files response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044101/how-to-add-headers-on-nuxt-static-files-response)

Comment: Nope, because that speak about the static folder, and is not the case :( thanks anyway

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The specific answer for GAE Apps, is the parameter `handlers.expiration` in `app.yaml` file:

```yaml
handlers:
  - url: /_nuxt
    static_dir: .nuxt/dist/client
    expiration: 4d 5h
    secure: always
```

Or if you want to configure it globally, set the `default_expiration` parameter at the root level:

```yaml
default_expiration: 4d 5h
```

Allows `d` (days), `h` (hours), `m` (minutes) and `s` (seconds). Here's the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_element)

Answer (score 3):

You can serve your static folder with custom cache policy following the [render configuration](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-render/#static).

As an example:

```js
render: {
  // Setting up cache for 'static' directory - a year in milliseconds
  // https://web.dev/uses-long-cache-ttl
  static: {
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 1000,
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the question doesn't talk about the static folder.

Comment: Just a note that you may want to change to `static: false;` if using GAE's CDN.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer, please note that - at the time of writing - the minimum time required by Lighthouse to pass is > 96.5d (Source : https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/11380)

I've followed the answer by @lmfresneda and managed to get the solution to work, making the cache time 30d : I still had the Lighthouse test fail until I changed it to "97d".

Comment: Thanks. Good point to keep in mind