# How to set X-Frame-Options in Nuxt.js/Vue.js app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, x-frame-options, nuxtjs

I want to load a web page inside a `iframe` tag element.

For example:
`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/" title="Google"></iframe>`

Which gives me this error:
`Refused to display 'https://www.google.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.`

How can I solve this problem in Nuxt.js app (or Vue.js - it should be very similar config)? I tried with nuxt-helmet, but according to dosc I can use either **DENY** or **SAMEORIGIN** because **ALLOW-FROM** has limited browser support.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set 'X-Frame-Options' on iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe)

Comment: You cant. thats a header form `google.com`.

Comment: I suggest you to read this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27358966/how-to-set-x-frame-options-on-iframe I advise you that in most cases, you should not use iframe. However, if you really need it, see this post as it contains your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044101/how-to-add-headers-on-nuxt-static-files-response