# How to set custom response headers for NuxtJS's SSR server?

Tags: http-headers, nuxt.js

I need to set these two custom response headers to [enable certain features](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy#certain_features_depend_on_cross-origin_isolation) in my site:

```
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
```

How can I do this in a NuxtJS app? I would like to do it for both the dev and production servers.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52044101/how-to-add-headers-on-nuxt-static-files-response. Although, I'm not sure if it will work on production mode.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Mani for the sharing. I copy the idea to add the below response header on my nuxt, and i test my docker img local and aws ecs's dev and prod env both can work.

X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN

X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff

First create a new js e.g. headers.js, i put under server-middleware because i also have logging file.

---

headers.js

```
module.exports = function (req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN')
  res.setHeader('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff')
  next()
}
```

---

nuxt.config.js

```
  export default {
    serverMiddleware: [
      '~/server-middleware/headers'
    ]
  }
```