# Nuxt Security: Fix missing headers

Tags: nuxt.js

How to set the following headers in Nuxt website?

1. Strict-Transport-Security
2. Content Security Policy
3. X-Frame-Options
4. X-Content-Type-Options
5. Referrer-Policy
6. Permissions-Policy

Comment: This question similar to this and there already have the answer which you can refer.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229680/how-to-set-custom-response-headers-for-nuxtjss-ssr-server/72906282#72906282

Answer (score -1):

these sound like a server config rather than nuxt itself.

for example I had a nuxt built website with `ssr: false` and `target: static` in `nuxt.config.js` and I was deploying the site using `IIS 10`.

in the root folder of the app I had a `web.config` file for the `IIS` to use and it contained some of the headers like:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering removeServerHeader="true">
          </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
                <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" />
                <add name="Strict-Transport-Security" value="max-age=31536000" />
                <add name="Content-Security-Policy" value="default-src 'self'; script-src 'self'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

side note: I had some issues in the app when using `Content-Security-Policy` so I ended up removing that line; and `web.config` had more configurations but shortened it here for readability