# How can I add the X-XSS-Protection header in nuxtjs?

Tags: nuxt.js, xss

I would like to set the `X-XSS-Protection` header to `1; mode=block` in my Nuxt application. How am I able to do this?!

I am using [nuxt-helmet](https://github.com/victor-perez/nuxt-helmet#readme), but helmet does not allow any options for X-XSS-Protection, it is either set at 0 or unset.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, this answer helped me. Just needed to set the response header in the server middleware.

[How to set custom response headers for NuxtJS's SSR server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69229680/how-to-set-custom-response-headers-for-nuxtjss-ssr-server)